# can't get dependencies from jitpack.io

Tags: android, gradle, jitpack

Today I failed in sync my android project. The error msg is below
"ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.huangyanbin:smartTable:2.2.0."
My build.gradle(Project) file is like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle(App) file is like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.xutils:xutils:3.5.1'
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.poi'
    }
    implementation group: 'com.belerweb', name: 'pinyin4j', version: '2.5.1'
    implementation group: 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2', name: 'rxpermissions', version: '0.9.5'
    implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxandroid', version: '2.1.1'
    implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.2.7'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.6'
    implementation group: 'com.haotek.ksoap2', name: 'ksoap2-android-assembly', version: '3.3.0'
    implementation group: 'androidx.multidex', name: 'multidex', version: '2.0.0'
    implementation group: 'dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'jaxen', name: 'jaxen', version: '1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.huangyanbin:smartTable:2.2.0'
    implementation group: 'com.github.wandersnail', name: 'treeadapter', version: '1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Are my settings correct?

Comment: The root cause of the error is aliyun.

Comment: Can u explain it more clearly?